# Yocto doesn't pack busybox syslog files

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using Yocto 2.3 to build my device image.
My image includes `packagegroup-core-boot` that, in turn, includes `busybox`.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL = "\
    ....
    packagegroup-core-boot \
```

Busybox is configured to include syslogd:

```
CONFIG_SYSLOGD=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_ROTATE_LOGFILE=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_REMOTE_LOG=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SYSLOGD_DUP=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SYSLOGD_CFG=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SYSLOGD_READ_BUFFER_SIZE=256
CONFIG_FEATURE_IPC_SYSLOG=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_IPC_SYSLOG_BUFFER_SIZE=64
CONFIG_LOGREAD=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_LOGREAD_REDUCED_LOCKING=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_KMSG_SYSLOG=y
CONFIG_KLOGD=y
```

It is built and installed correctly.
Relevant syslog files do appear in busybox `image` directory:

```
tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.24.1-r0/image$ tree etc/
etc/
├── default
├── init.d
│   └── syslog.busybox
├── syslog.conf.busybox
├── syslog-startup.conf.busybox
```

These files don't appear in my main image rootfs, though. Only the `syslogd` command is included. See output on target device:

```
# ls -l $( which syslogd )
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            19 Jan 10 12:31 /sbin/syslogd -> /bin/busybox.nosuid
```

What can be happening to make this files not to be included in the final image?

---

Additional question:

As shown in the `tree` output, the init script for syslog is included in busybox but no link to `/etc/rc?.d/` is created.
I understand that is should be created by a `do_install()` hook, shouldn't?

Thanks in advance.

---

*EDIT*

Contents of `packages-split`, as @Anders says, seems ok:

```
poky/build-idprint/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.24.1-r0$ tree packages-split/busybox-syslog/
packages-split/busybox-syslog/
└── etc
    ├── init.d
    │   ├── syslog
    │   └── syslog.busybox
    ├── syslog.conf
    ├── syslog.conf.busybox
    ├── syslog-startup.conf
    └── syslog-startup.conf.busybox
```

I just can't figure out what is stripping this files out of the final image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.24.1-r0/packages-split`. This is where all files are split into the packages that will be generated. If you search that directory, you'll find eg `syslog.conf` in the `busybox-syslog` package.

Thus, in order to get those files into your image, you'll need to add `busybox-syslog` to your image. I.e. `IMAGE_INSTALL += "busybox-syslog"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Anders. I actually do have a `packages-split/busybox-syslog/` dir with the needed files in but why do these don't get into my final image? How to fix that? What might be stripping this files out? Thanks again.

Comment: Added instructions to add the generated package to your image.

Comment: Curious... so `packagegroup-core-boot` that implies in installing busybox does not imply installing `busybox-syslog` or any other enabled feature?

Comment: No, not necessarily. You might very well have two different images, though you only want to use busybox-syslog in one of them. (Maybe you're using systemd-journald in the large image, and busybox-syslog in your smaller image, as an example).

Comment: Great! That's exactly the kind of solution I love most. A single line of text solves it all (including the symlinks in "/etc/rc?.d"). I owe you a beer!